# Is it possible to install ubuntu inside the RAM?

Tags: ram

Is it possible to install Ubuntu inside the ram so it will run fast as light?If yes then,how?I am going to buy 64 GB RAM laptop.

Also can I load all system files like entire / in RAM except /home and other partitions while booting up the system?.I always have /home on separate partition.

Comment: One way is using a _Live CD/Edition_. It gets pretty close, but doesn't copy all files to RAM.

Comment: You cannot 'install' any application into RAM. RAM by its nature is volatile. This means that when you turn off the machine, the application is gone. A live disk is your best option. Alternatively, you can use an SSD for you install drive. It's almost as fast as RAM

Comment: I don't know the exact details but it is possible to make a RAM disk and load an image into it. the difficulty with this is that RAM is not persistent. any changes you make will be lost unless you figure a way to write it to disk. which reduces your efficiency. also boot time will be very long if you load an entire installation to RAM  -----  10 minutes to transer 20GB of data from a disk

Comment: @ThatGuy that is what a "cloud" does when you install Ubuntu OS in the cloud.  "so it will run fast as light". Nope.

Comment: An Ubuntu live system (live-only or persistent live) can use the boot option `toram` to load the content coming from the iso file to RAM.  An installed system can be treated in a more advanced way for the same purpose as described at the following link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594694

Comment: You can use the option toram with a persistent flash drive, Mkusb has a grub option to run in RAM with persistence.

Comment: @rinzwind cloud services use images loaded in RAM, not installed. Usually they're custom images developed for their platform OpenVZ; KVM etc. But he wasn't asking about hypervisors.

Answer (score 3):

No. RAM is not persistent storage. You can only install to persistent storage media, such as an SSD.

You could create a ramdisk image, and load it into memory during boot, but anything stored in RAM as a result, will mean less memory for the programs to actually use when running.

Really, what you're asking is not feasible, and general computing systems like the laptop you mention you're buying, are not designed to work this way.